# java парсинг веб страницы

Tags: java, html, dom, jsoup, sax

Ранее с парсингом не сталкивался, а тут перед мной постала такая проблема, есть несколько определенных веб страниц одна из них - https://cybermap.kaspersky.com/
задача заключается в том, что необходимо достать информацию по конкретной стране, а именно виды кибератак ,их количество, каким образом вообще возможно это реализовать подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли это сделать с помощью jsoup или используя стандартные парсеры и каким образом, заранее спасибо.

Comment: Генератором случайных чисел сделайте свою статистику. Факт все поступают так же. Где надо вероятности делают побольше, где поменьше

Answer (score 1):

FLV страничку парсить jsoup api не умеет, так что вряд ли

Comment: спасибо, а каким тогда образом можно решить данную задачу?